# android studio 4.2.1 upgrade problems

Tags: flutter

Android Studio 4.2.1 on Windows 10. Latest stable Flutter version.
If I create a Flutter project I have no database inspector, no profiler and no emulator window, no evd manager under tools menu. Also Device File explorer is gone and i cannot search my database adb file.
Flutter doctor gives no error.
Everything worked fine until the upgrade to 4.2.1
What’s going on? how can i get those tools back? Thank you